# How to calculate the total sum end of each loop?

Tags: php

I am fetching the data from the table "daybook" according to date.I haved fetched data and display in the front-end also.

My problem is i have two column debit and credit,it displays the amount.I have to calculate the sum of this at each end of looping.

My expected result:
[image]

My code:
My view page code:

```
<tbody>
<?php
    $totalQuantity = 0;
    $totalBundle = 0;
    $rowcount = 1;
    foreach ($query as $key => $value){
        $counter = 0;
?>
<?php
    foreach ($value as $sub_key => $sub_value) {
        if($counter == 0) {
            if ($sub_value['dc']== "D"){ 
                $totalQuantity  + = $sub_value['Amount'];
            }
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $sub_value['code'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($sub_value['date1']));?></td>
            <td><?php echo $sub_value['part'] ?></td>
            <td><?php if ($sub_value['dc']== "D"){ echo $sub_value['Amount'];} ?></td>
            <td><?php if ($sub_value['dc']== "C"){ echo $sub_value['Amount'];} ?></td>
            <?php $rowcount +=1?>
        </tr>
<?php
    $counter++;
}else {?>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo $sub_value['part'];?></td>
            <td><?php if ($sub_value['dc']== "D"){ echo $sub_value['Amount'];} ?></td>
            <td><?php if ($sub_value['dc']== "C"){ echo $sub_value['Amount'];} ?></td>
        </tr>   
<?php
            } // else
        } // foreach
    }
    ?> 
    <tr>

        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td><?php echo $totalQuantity; ?></td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

please help me to solve the sum of debit and credit in each one.
My output:

[image]

Comment: I think you can directly count the sum using SQL query rather then using PHP.

Comment: The amount column  in table stores the value both c and d the how i separate and calculate the sum

Answer (score 2):

Remove Space between  "+ ="

```
$totalQuantity  += $sub_value['Amount'];
```

Comment: End fo the loop.

Comment: Hey if use in end of the loop it calculate the whole row total

Comment: I want the total for each one

Comment: add new two variable in if condition " $totalCredits += $sub_value['Amount']; " And " $totalDebits += $v['trans_amt']; "

Comment: kk in which place i print the result

Comment: End of the loop.

Comment: please see my picture what i need

Comment: your picture and your code is different. But i Got it your point.

Comment: you need Credit and Debit Total and Closing Balance Right ?

Comment: Show me your output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187776/discussion-between-tom-and-nimesh-patel).